# Printing Sentences in Java

Tags: java, hyperlink

I have a method that reads from a URL and splits the text into sentences using a delimiter. Here's what I have:

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("Some link");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String l;

        while((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String sentence = l.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z?.!]"," ");
            String[] sent = sentence.split("[?.!]", 2);
            for(int x = 0; x < sent.length; x++) {
                System.out.println(sent[x]);            
        }       
    }
            in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException me) {
        System.out.println(me);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }
```

This prints out the text sentence by sentence. However, I would like to read 30 sentences at a time, just wondering how I would go about doing that.

Comment: What do you mean at a time? You could just loop 50 times no?

Comment: Yes, but when I loop 50 times, it prints 50 lines, not 50 sentences. I would like to read x number of sentences, rather than x number of lines.

Comment: Ok got it. I'm posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a StringBuilder to concatenate the whole text to work with first, then split it with a point and finally loop over it 50 times printing the 50 first indexes of the whole text array.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();    
while((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(l);
}
String[] sentences = sb.toString().split(".");
for (int i = 0 ; i < 50 ; i++){
    System.out.println(sentences[i]);
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it is still printing out all of the text, basically ignoring the "i < 50"

Comment: mmh what is the still you're trying to print from? Then I'll try it.

Comment: Nevermind, I made a type in the code! It now prints out 50 sentences. The only thing is, it is formatted very strange. Any way to fix the formatting issues?